# What does the '-' operator actually do in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I see the `-` operator behaving in different ways with different commands.

For example,

```
cd -
```

cds to the previous directory, whereas,

```
vim -
```

reads from `stdin`

So I want to know why the `-` operator is behaving in 2 different ways here. Can someone point me to some detailed documentation of the `-` operator?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not an operator, it is an argument. When you write a program in C or C++ it comes as `argv[1]` (when it is the first argument) and you can do whatever you like with it.

By convention, many programs use `-` as a placeholder for stdin where an input file name is normally required, and stdout where an output file name is expected. But `cd` does not require reading a file stream, why should it need stdin or stdout?

Extra: here below is the excerpt from vim's `main.c` that parses arguments that begin with `-`: if there is no additional character it activates STDIN input.

```
    else if (argv[0][0] == '-' && !had_minmin)
    {
        want_argument = FALSE;
        c = argv[0][argv_idx++];
#ifdef VMS
        ...
#endif
        switch (c)
        {
        case NUL:       /* "vim -"  read from stdin */
                /* "ex -" silent mode */
        if (exmode_active)
            silent_mode = TRUE;
        else
        {
            if (parmp->edit_type != EDIT_NONE)
            mainerr(ME_TOO_MANY_ARGS, (char_u *)argv[0]);
            parmp->edit_type = EDIT_STDIN;
            read_cmd_fd = 2;    /* read from stderr instead of stdin */
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. How should I know how different (standard) commands use it? If the program decides how to use it, why not any other symbol like `!`, or `#`?

Comment: @Stacker: Each program that is decent has a good documentation. How to invoke the program and what it accepts on the command line should be documented. In vim, I admit that it's not easy, but you can find it at `:help --` (how confusing, but `:help -` goes to the `-` command in normal mode).

Answer (score 3):

The dash on its own is a simple command argument.  Its meaning is command dependent.  Its two most usual meanings are 'standard input' or (less often) 'standard output'.  The meaning of 'previous directory' is unique to the `cd` shell built-in (and it only means that in some shells, not all shells).

```
cat file1 - file2 | troff ...
```

This means read `file1`, standard input, and `file2` in that sequence and send the output to `troff`.

An extreme case of using `-` to mean 'standard input' or 'standard output' comes from (GNU) `tar`:

```
generate_file_list ... |
tar -cf - -T - |
( cd /some/where/else; tar -xf - )
```

The `-cf -` options in the first `tar` mean 'create an archive' and 'the output file is standard output'; the `-T -` option means 'read the list of files and/or directories from standard input'.

The `-xf -` options in the second `tar` mean 'extract an archive' and 'the input file is standard input'.  In fact, GNU `tar` has an option `-C /some/where/else` which means it does the `cd` itself, so the whole command could be:

```
generate_file_list ... |
tar -cf - -T - |
tar -xf - -C /some/where/else
```

The net effect of this is to copy the files named by the `generate_file_list` command from under the 'current directory' to `/some/where/else`, preserving the directory structure.  (The 'current directory' has to be taken with a small pinch of salt; any absolute file names are given special treatment by GNU `tar` — it removes the leading slash — and relative names are taken as relative to the current directory.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the program it's being used in. It means different things to different programs.

Answer (score 0):

I think different program use different convention. manpages shows how each program interpret -, here is `man bash`

```
-
    At shell startup, set to the absolute pathname used to invoke the shell
    or shell script being executed as passed in the environment or argument list.
    Subsequently, expands to the last argument to the previous command, after expansion.
    Also set to the full pathname used to invoke each command executed and placed 
    in the environment exported to that command. When checking mail, this parameter
    holds the name of the mail file currently being checked.
```

and `man vim`

```
 - The file to edit is read from stdin.  Commands are read from stderr, 
    which should be a tty.
```